# Free body diagram (FBD) of a beaker having water and a block

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, free-body-diagram, buoyancy, fluid-statics

Suppose there is a wooden block in a liquid in beaker. 
So there would be MG, buoyant force downwards, and normal contact force due to water also right? Would that be all the forces?

Answer (score 1):

The buoyant force IS the contact force.

**Forces are**:-

*For the block:* Its own weight and the buoyant force(or "contact force") by the liquid.

*For the liquid:* Its own weight, the contact force by block (equal and opposite to the buoyant force by the liquid on the block) and the contact force by the beaker.

These are all if you consider liquid and block. I see you also got the direction of buoyant force wrong too. It would actually be upwards on the block.